# Sums of degenerate quadratic forms

Tags: normal-distribution, convolution, quadratic-form

I am searching for an analogue of the fact: let $\Sigma_1 , \Sigma_2> 0$ in $\mathbb R^{m \times m}$ and let $x,c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb R^m$ be arbitrary. Let $\Sigma_3^{-1} = \Sigma_1^{-1} + \Sigma_2^{-1}$ 
Then, $$(x-c_1)^T\Sigma_1^{-1}(x-c_1) + (x-c_2)^T\Sigma_2^{-1}(x-c_2) = (x-c_3)^T[\Sigma_1^{-1} + \Sigma_2^{-1}](x-c_3) + (c_1-c_2)^T[\Sigma_1 + \Sigma_2]^{-1}(c_1-c_2)$$ 
where $\Sigma_3^{-1}c_3 = \Sigma_1^{-1}c_1 + \Sigma_2^{-1}c_2$.

**Question:** what happens when $\Sigma_2$ is only positive *semidefinite*?
Or, what is $$x-c_1)^T\Sigma_1^{-1}(x-c_1) + (x-c_2)^T\Sigma_2^{+}(x-c_2)$$ where $\Sigma_2^+$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse. (We can restrict $x-c_2$ to be in the span of $\Sigma_2$ if needed.)

Comment: Where is the connection to statistics or machine learning? Without such connection, this Q belongs on math SE

Comment: This computation arises in the convolution of multivariate normal random variables.